# Найти угол, образованный векторами

Tags: математика, вектор

Задача: найти угол, образованный векторами `p = 3a-2b` и `q = 7b+2a`,
если известно, что угол между векторами `a` и `b` равен 90 градусов, `|a| = 4`,
`|b| = 3`.

Я так понимаю, необходимо найти координаты векторов `а` и `b`, отталкиваясь от свойства ортогональности (90 градусов) векторов. Но как это сделать не знаю, из этих свойств нашел только одно:

```
x1 * x2 + y1 * y2 = 0
```

Подскажите, как найти этот угол?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Это сайт по вопросам по программированию, возможно вам необходимо задать этот вопрос на специализированном сайте.

Comment: Жаль, просто увидел раздел Математика. Видимо тут алгебра не раздел математики.

Comment: Математика, конечно тут есть но она должна быть по теме программирования.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что данная математика не касается программирования

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тю! :) Скалярное произведение векторов дает угол:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дальше пояснять? :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Остается подставить вместо `a` - 4, вместо `b` - 3 и посчитать...

Comment: Большое вам спасибо!

Comment: Кстати, в названии смешно написано - потому что угол между ортогональными векторами всегда 90 градусов :)

Comment: Хм,  в формуле косинуса двух веторов в числители должны быть их координаты, но у меня по условию нет координат, есть только длинна вектора. Вы не подскажите, как найти эти координаты?

Comment: Какие еще координаты? Зачем они вам? Просто при скалярном перемножении p и q пользуемся тем, что a*a и b*b равны квадратам длин a и b, а a*b=b*a=0. Все. И, поскольку a и b ортогональны, длины p и q определяются по теореме Пифагора :) Вот и все. Никаких координат **не нужно**. Конечно, можно считать, что a направлен по оси X, а b - по Y, но это **не нужно**.